# How to update and delete firebase data in android java?

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting nothing in response while updating or deleting the data this line but the inserting and retriving works fine and please do answer i am new to android development

```
 @Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ToDoHolder holder,int position, @NonNull ToDoItem model) {

    holder.delete.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(holder.delete.getContext());
        String deleteId = model.getUid();
        builder.setTitle("Delete Panel");
        builder.setMessage("Delete...?");

        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", (dialogInterface, i) -> mDatabase.child("todos")
                .child(deleteId).removeValue());

        builder.setNegativeButton("No", (dialogInterface, i) -> {

        });

        builder.show();
    });

}
```

Comment: did you check if deleteId is proper or not

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the .removeValue() operation to see if something goes wrong?